# use of using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE for an DML Statement in Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, execute-immediate

I am new to PL SQL Procedures , we have this line of code inside the Execution section of a Stored Procedure .

I am having a query here , please tell me whats the use of using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for a DML Statement Here ? and in what cases we should use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`?

```
v_update_query2 := 'INSERT INTO '||p_country||'.DETAILS ( ID, STATUS, DEST_SYSTEM, OUT_TIME ) VALUES ('''
    ||v_txn_id ||''','||'''T081'''||','||'''CLEARING'''||', SYSDATE)';



EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_update_query1 ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is the only way to have variable references to schema objects - eg table names, column names etc.

It allows you to build up *any* string and then execute that string as an SQL statement.
Without it, procedure variables can only be used for values in sql, eg `select * from table where column = my_variable`

In your example, the *table name* is being provided by the `p_country` variable - that's a schema element, so you need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Comment: Bohemian is entirely correct, howver, you should also research dynamic SQL in the documentation and replace your literals with bind variables for both performance and security from SQL Injection.

Comment: You can't replace the reference to schema objects within dynamic sql with bind variables, so `p_country` will still be a problem. In SQL Server I would use `quotename` on `p_country` to make it safe. I do not know the equivelent in Oracle land.